# Dynamic Data Flow to separate unique records in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to read Parquet Files dynamically and extract unique records. Each file can have 1 or more key Columns.

1. Assuming the files are going to have 1 key column I have designed the below data flow with `ID` parameter.
   [image: Basic Data Flow]
2. In the aggregate transformation, I am grouping by the `ID` Column
   [image: grouping by parameterized ID Column]
   Also allowing all other columns to pass-through
   [image: Allowing remaining columns to Flow through]
   **Note**: please observe the Column is being read as `ID` and not AddressID
3. In the next step in select, I am trying to rename this ID as AddressID(using the parameter value).
   [image: renaming the ID column to original key column name]
   the output show like this
   [image: Doesnt Work]

---

**I have tried giving values in names as hardcoded value (Address ID) and it
works.**

---

Can some help me on how to rename this ID with AddressId (parameter value which key column name) dynamically?

Also, the above scenario is possible when there is 1 key column.
Is it possible to use the Azure Data Factory to handle a scenario when there are more than 1 key columns and process it dynamically?

Depending on this we will use adf or use ADB.

Data Flow Code:

```
{
    "name": "RemoveDuplicateRows",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DS_Parquet_DF",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DS_Parquet_Cleaned",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "Aggregate1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Select1"
                }
            ],
            "script": "parameters{\n\tID as string ('AddressID')\n}\nsource(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet',\n\tpartitionBy('roundRobin', 2)) ~> source1\nsource1 aggregate(groupBy(ID = byName($ID)),\n\teach(match(name!=$ID), $$ = first($$))) ~> Aggregate1\nAggregate1 select(mapColumn(\n\t\teach(match(name=='ID'),\n\t\t\t'AddressID' = $$),\n\t\teach(match(name!='ID'))\n\t),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> Select1\nSelect1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tformat: 'parquet',\n\ttruncate: true,\n\tpartitionBy('roundRobin', 2),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1"
        }
    }
}
```

DataFlow Script

```
parameters{
    ID as string ('AddressID')
}
source(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    format: 'parquet',
    partitionBy('roundRobin', 2)) ~> source1
source1 aggregate(groupBy(ID = byName($ID)),
    each(match(name!=$ID), $$ = first($$))) ~> Aggregate1
Aggregate1 select(mapColumn(
        each(match(name=='ID'),
            'AddressID' = $$),
        each(match(name!='ID'))
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> Select1
Select1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    format: 'parquet',
    truncate: true,
    partitionBy('roundRobin', 2),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> sink1
```

Comment: Would you mind to copy & paste the data flow script (use the Script button on top of data flow designer) here so I can see the entire script behind?

Comment: @markKromer  i have added the script and code for reference.... Thank you

Comment: Thx ... this looks like a bug and I am able to repro it. I've sent a note over to ADF engineering. But it would be helpful if you could paste your script and description using the ADF feedback (smiley face) to ensure we can have someone pick it up quickly.

Comment: In the interim, it appears that literal strings work, even if that is not as flexible.

Comment: MarkKromer..... thank you for the reply and also just wanted to know if the number of key columns change ....can we create a data flow...the above will work if there is only one key column...In the group by how can we add and decrease columns dynamically

Comment: For dynamic columns in group by, you can set a string[] array parameter and then use this formula in the group-by in your Aggregate: array(byNames($parameter1))